# Author Dropdown Select Field in a SafeCracker Form

Tags: expressionengine

Is it possible to have an author dropdown select field in a SafeCracker form, in a similar way to how you can have a Status dropdown select field with the following code?

```
{status_menu}
  <label for="status">Status</label>
    <select name="status" id="status">
      {select_options}
    </select>
{/status_menu}
```

I've searched the docs and EE forums but can't find anything, but hoping there's a way of doing this.

Thanks for any help,

Ste

Edit:

Thanks to Tyssen's reply below, I've just implemented this solution in a SafeCracker form and it works great. Just one note though - the name should be author_id rather than author. Here's my final code, including a conditional to show the entry's current author:

```
<label>Author</label>
<select name="author_id">
{exp:query sql="SELECT member_id, screen_name, group_id FROM exp_members ORDER BY screen_name ASC;"}
  <option value="{member_id}" {if "{member_id}" == "{author_id}"}selected="selected"{/if}>{screen_name}</option>
{/exp:query}
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the query module maybe?

```
<select name="author">
{exp:query sql="SELECT member_id, screen_name
    FROM exp_members
    WHERE group_id = X;"
}
    <option value="{member_id}">{screen_name}</option>
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: Thanks Tyssen - I didn't even think about using the query module, but that will do the trick nicely, thanks. :)